# How do I add lazy loading to my product page on Shopify?

Tags: shopify, lazy-loading, liquid

I would like to speed up my Shopify website load time by lazyloading my images. The problem is that I cannot locate the specific image files in the code in order to add the class= "lazyload" to it.

Here is what I have tried:
I have pasted this code at the top of the product-template.liquid page:

```
<!--Lazy Loading -->
{{ "lazysizes.min.js" | asset_url | script_tag }}
<style>.lazyload,.lazyloading{opacity:0}.lazyloaded{opacity:1;transition:opacity.3s}</style>
```

And then adding the code: class= "lazyload" to the end of any chunk of code that I think looks like an image, but it doesn't work.
[Product-template.liquid page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owqmq.png)  [page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuIUg.png)  [page3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Sed.png)

Would anyone be able to help me understand where this code goes and how to identify where I need to put the code to lazyload an image?

Comment: Please share the exact error and how you say it's not working. Will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using `<img src="..." />` . For lazyload to work, change it to `<img data-src="..." />`

And the better alternative is to implement native lazy loading. Just add `loading="lazy"` to your images and voila.

Ex: `<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"  loading="lazy" />`

More details & a combined use with lazyload library - https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/ & https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr

Answer (score 0):

In the online code editor, add the below code before close tag.

```
{{ '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.min.js' | script_tag }}
```

Add the class lazyload to images that should be lazy loaded. In addition, change the src attribute to data-src.

```
<img class="lazyload" data-src="image.jpg" />
```

Instead of

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```